# How to automatically open(click) a HTTP link from a mail body(outlook) message using C# in a Windows Application?

Tags: c#, outlook-2010, pop3

I want to automatically open or click a `http` link from the *Outlook* mail body.

I am using **MailServer**.
Here my code:

```
// Some function...     
    for (int i = 0; i < infos.Length; i++)
    {
        MailInfo info = infos[i];
        Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}; Size: {1}; UIDL: {2}; Flags: {3}",
            info.Index, info.Size, info.UIDL, info.Flags);

        // Receive email from POP3 server
        Mail oMail = oClient.GetMail(info);

        Console.WriteLine("From: {0}", oMail.From.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("To: {0}", oMail.To.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}\r\n", oMail.Subject);
        if (oMail.Attachments.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= oMail.Attachments.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                System.DateTime d = System.DateTime.Now;
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo cur = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
                string sdate = d.ToString("MMddyyyyHHmmss", cur);
                string fileName = String.Format("{0}\\{1}{2}{3}.eml", mailbox, sdate, d.Millisecond.ToString("d3"), i);
                // Save email to local disk
                oMail.SaveAs(fileName, true);
                // Save attachments in specific folders.
                oMail.Attachments[j].SaveAs(@"D:\"{Folder Name}"\" + oMail.Attachments[j].Name, true);  // find the said path
                // Mark email as deleted from POP3 server.
                oClient.Delete(info);
            }
        }
        // Generate an email file name based on date time.
    }
    // Quit and purge emails marked as deleted from POP3 server.
    oClient.Quit();
}
```

Please give me any idea.

Comment: I have to ask if you have a good reason to do this. Assuming you are not writing malware yourself, you could be reading phish and spam which is not something you want to automatically navigate to.

Comment: @Crowcoder No, actually I want to download files from that link automatically. Do u have any idea?

Comment: That still sounds sketchy to me, but I see two main tasks. Parse links out of the email body and then use HttpClient or some other http API to make a request.